# Static files not getting rendered using express

Tags: node.js, express

Jade template

```
doctype html
    html
      head
        title= title
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
        link(rel="stylesheet", href='/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css')
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css")
      body.bg-info
        nav.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-dark.bg-danger
              a.navbar-brand(href='/')  
                h3 Loc8r
              button.navbar-toggler(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#navbarSupportedContent', aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent', aria-expanded='false', aria-label='Toggle navigation')
                  span.navbar-toggler-icon
              #navbarSupportedContent.collapse.navbar-collapse
                  ul.navbar-nav.mr-auto
                    li.nav-item.ml-auto
                      a.nav-link(href='/about') About
                    li.nav-item.ml-auto
                      a.nav-link(href='/location') Location Info
                    li.nav-item.ml-auto
                      a.nav-link(href='/location/review/new') Add Review

        .container-fluid.my-5
          block content

          footer.footer
            .row
            .col-xs-12
            small &copy; Tushar Sharma 2020

        script(src='/bootstrap/jquery.min.js')

        script(src='/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js')
```

Error:
GET http://localhost:3000/bootstrap/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
I am getting the above error, My static files are present in public/bootstrap and they were getting rendered initially but now they are not, and I am not able to figure out any error.

```
app.use('/bootstrap',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

[image: image 3]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `app.use()` statement is in your application's base directory you can simply do this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This makes your entire `public` directory load statically, so in your Jade/Pug template when call this:

```
script(src='/bootstrap/jquery.min.js')
```

It is going to look in your `public/bootstrap` folder for the `jquery.min.js` file. Now let's examine the code you are currently using, where your implementation is the reverse of what you think it is:

```
app.use('/bootstrap',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

According to [Express documentation for serving static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), the `/bootstrap` path is a virtual path; In other words, in your templates `/bootstrap`is actually pointing to your base `public/` folder. which means when you are calling this:

```
script(src='/bootstrap/jquery.min.js')
```

then Express is actually looking for your file at `public/jquery.min.js`, because `/bootstrap` is aliased to your `public/` folder.

Comment: Thanks, it was very informative, but actually i tried with the earlier approach and the error was due to cache issue , after refreshing the cache it is working.

Comment: What cache are you referring to?

Comment: 301 error in the image, after refreshing the cache it started working, but when i move to different url then .js files stop loading

Comment: So are you still having issues or is everything resolved for you?

Comment: at this every thing is loading  localhost:3000, but at localhost:3000/location bootstrap.js and jquery.js are not loading status code 404

Comment: I would recommend re-reading my answer and the Express documentation to understand what the Express engine is doing, between those two you will find the solution.

Comment: Thanks Jason, please have a look at image 3 can you see find any error there, or is it fine for express to look for jquery.js file there?

Comment: I have no idea where that `/location` stuff is coming from. Instead of posting images it would be better to post more of your code, like when and where you define your routes. That `express.static()` call has to come *before* you define your routes.